# After for loop i get printed only one string path to image folder instead of multiple strings of images, python

Tags: python, django, for-loop

I have iterated over folder media/images that containsall paths to that folder images using os.walk() function. After I did for in loop i get only one image in that folder and there is more then 115 i think of images of Dota2 heroes.

I will show you the code and print screen so you can closely look. I think i made a mistake with for in loop some were but I new to python.

insert_heroes.py (lines 15 to 18 are the one that iterate over my media/images folder.)

```
import requests
import json
import os

API_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    r = requests.get("https://api.opendota.com/api/heroes")
    all_heroes_info = json.loads(r.content.decode('UTF-8'))

    for hero_info in all_heroes_info:
        name = hero_info['localized_name']
        hero_type = hero_info['primary_attr']

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk("../../media/images/", topdown=False):
        for image in files:
            pass
        print(image)

        keys = [name]
        values = [image]
        # dictionary = dist(zip(keys, values))
        # print(dictionary)
        # print(keys)

        mutation_create_hero = '''
                  mutation ($name: String!, $heroType: String!, $image: String!) {
                      createHero(name: $name, heroType: $heroType, image: $image) {
                          name
                          image
                      }
                  }
              '''
        variables = {'name': name, 'heroType': hero_type, 'image': image}

        # localhost_api_response = requests.post(
        #     '{}/graphql/'.format(API_URL),
        #     json={
        #         'query': mutation_create_hero,
        #         'variables': variables
        #     }
        # )
```

What i get is this, when I print image variable -- https://prnt.sc/qmzh8g
Only 1 icon. Zeus icon.png that is last image file in media/images dir.

Thanks

Comment: Your print is under the loop, not in the loop... After the loop, the iterator variable `image` is equal to the last element of `files`. You need to print IN the loop to get all images.

Comment: can you write me that in answer please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change lines 15-18 from

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("../../media/images/", topdown=False):
    for image in files:
        pass
    print(image)
```

to:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("../../media/images/", topdown=False):
    for image in files:
        print(image)
```

Your indentation was slightly off on the print. The `print` statement was in the loop but outside of the inner loop.